# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method nextInt()

Tags: java, arraylist, random

I used the Random class to generate the number from 1 to 20. Then, I added it into a ArrayList, but the error message showed "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method nextInt(int) from the type Random". How could I do? Below is my code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class ComputerChoose {

static ArrayList<Integer> computer_number = new ArrayList<>();

public static ArrayList<Integer> getTheNumber() {

    for(int times=0; times<5; times++)
    {
        computer_number.add(Random.nextInt(20) + 1);
    }

    return computer_number;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `nextInt` is an instance method, not a static one. You need to create an instance of `Random`, i.e. `Random r = new Random();`

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with putting the result in an array. You could have isolated the problem by first trying the simpler task of creating a simple variable containing a random number. Stripping down problems to the simplest form makes for the best SO questions -- and often in the process you solve it for yourself.

Comment: Also ArrayList can have duplicates, then either check if number already exists in the list and do not put it if so, or use one of the `java.util.Set` implementations. `Set` has no duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nextInt` is not a static method. You have to **create an instance of `Random`**, and call it as an instance method:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class ComputerChoose {

    static ArrayList<Integer> computer_number = new ArrayList<>();

    public static ArrayList<Integer> getTheNumber() {
        Random random = new Random();

        for(int times=0; times<5; times++) {
            computer_number.add(random.nextInt(20) + 1);
        }

        return computer_number;
    }
}
```

---

[See also the JavaDocs for `java.util.Random`.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> getTheNumber() {
    Random rand = new Random(); // create instance of Random class
    for(int times=0; times<5; times++)
    {
        computer_number.add(rand.nextInt(20) + 1);
    }
    return computer_number;
}
```